# Is it possible to get the value of a type as a constant

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to do something like:

```
type TrueType = true;
const someVar = GetTypeValue<TrueType>(); // This is where the value true is written
```

Is it possible to write other constant values to constant variables like in C++?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. WHat do you expect from `Value` function ?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine return a value of type 'TrueType'. At compile time it outputs a value of true, and I would like to write it into a variable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing helps at compile time but not at runtime.

You can use this strategy at compile time to get the value safely:

```
type TrueType = true;
const myTrue: TrueType = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the typescript world it's better to think of it the other way round if you need to use a constant as a runtime value. Define the constant, (so Javascript has it) then derive the type from it (so Typescript has it).

```js
const GREAT_WORD = 'Discombobulate';
type GreatWord = typeof GREAT_WORD;


const SOUNDS_LIKE = 'Onomatopoeia'
const GOINGS_ON = 'Shenanigans'
const ALL_OVER = 'Ubiquitous'
const LESSER_WORDS = [SOUNDS_LIKE,GOINGS_ON, ALL_OVER];
type LesserWord = typeof LESSER_WORDS[number]

function say(word: GreatWord | LesserWord){
  console.log(word)
}


say(GREAT_WORD)
say(SOUNDS_LIKE)
say(GOINGS_ON)
say(ALL_OVER)

say('Discombobulate')
say('Shenanigans')
```